# node.js job partition over specific CPU subset

Tags: node.js, linux

I have 2 node.js programs that communicate with each other through a socket. I originally intended on running them on separate linux machines, but realized it would be much simpler to have them both on one multi-core machine, each allocated a specific subset of the total CPUs. For example, I have a machine with 8 cores, I want to run program_A on 2 cores as 1 process (using node's fork module), and program_B on the remaining 6 cores, also as a single process forked over several cores. Is there any way to do this with node.js? I'm aware of `taskset` to set CPU affinity, but I'm not quite sure if that would work for this scenario.